# App crashing because of onclick?

Tags: java, android

While I was testing my app on a virtual device, I faced the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.attendancekeeper.mohilkhare.attendancekeeper, PID: 4150
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
                  at com.attendancekeeper.mohilkhare.attendancekeeper.MainActivity.displayMessageOnnumOfTotalDays(MainActivity.java:32)
                  at com.attendancekeeper.mohilkhare.attendancekeeper.MainActivity.present(MainActivity.java:25)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This error came when I added the following to MainActivity.java:

- A function that incremented a couple of integers and displayed the values to text view targetted using text view id.

Can anyone please explain why is this happening? I am new to this.

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
 that's why, apparently

Comment: Please add the relevant code sniplet of the xml file and the java code

Comment: @Mohil khare, did you initialized your button ?

Comment: @Mohil Khare Please check anywhere you are setting integer value(or non string value) to textview or button

Comment: @JineshFrancis I have commented the relevant java and xml code

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I've commented the relevant code now

Comment: @HemantParmar Yes. Or he would get an NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because you set int value in TextView.Because setText() accepts only String values or Resource ID of a String (which is infact int).

change

```
displayMessageOnnumOfTotalDays.setText(totalDays);

displayMessageOntv1.setText(daysAttended);
```

To

```
 displayMessageOnnumOfTotalDays.setText(String.valueOf(totalDays));

 displayMessageOntv1.setText(String.valueOf(daysAttended));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Apart from this all I had to do was change

`private void displayMessageOnnumOfTotalDays(int totalDays)`
and
`private void displayMessageOntv1(int daysAttended)`

to

`private void displayMessageOnnumOfTotalDays(String totalDays)`
and
`private void displayMessageOntv1(String daysAttended)`

respectively!

Comment: @MohilKhare happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As well as you can use following way.

```
displayMessageOnnumOfTotalDays.setText(String.valueOf(totalDays));
displayMessageOntv1.setText(String.valueOf(daysAttended));
```